# Wiggling value according a given step

Tags: after-effects

I think the question is obvious: for example: how can i wiggle opacity randomly using "wiggler" with a given step (not talking about the frequency)? Let's say i want to randomly wiggle from 0 to 100, like switching on & off?

Comment: So doing something like wiggle(5,100) doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an expression to create random movement with the wiggle expression in After Effects.

Hit Option (Mac) or Alt (PC) click on the stopwatch to create the expression. The text turns Red, telling you there is an expression applied.

Type wiggle(2,50). This expression states that twice a second the text should wiggle 50 pixels on the x & y axis – the first number is how many times a second, the 2nd is the amount of pixel movement.

If you want to modify the wiggle simply change the numbers.

This is the expression they have for ‘wiggle in one dimension’:

```
wiggle only in x (horizontal):

org=value; temp=wiggle (5,50); [temp[0],org[1]];

Shorthand:

[wiggle(5,50)[0],position[1]]

wiggle only in y (vertical):

org=value; temp=wiggle (5,50); [org[0],temp[1]];
```